# Dell Inspiron 15z not shutting down due to Intel Rapid Start Technology driver

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-8.1, drivers, intel-rapid-start

My Laptop consists of 500GB HDD , 32GB SSD and 6GB RAM

A few days back, I accidentally uninstalled the Intel Rapid Start Technology driver.  After that, my laptop started beeping 5 times at start-up.

Along with this, my laptop was not shutting down; the display turns off, the fan runs faster and the power button LED and keyboard backlight remains on.  When the laptop goes into sleep, it will not turn back on and the same power button LED and keyboard backlight, etc. remain turned on.

I found that the 5 beep sound is for CMOS battery replacement. So I replaced the CMOS battery and the beeping during boot disappeared.

However, the laptop still doesn't shutdown. I did a recovery of Windows 8 but the problem remains.

I have installed Windows 10, but it's still the same.  Then I did a clean install of Windows 8.1, cleaned the SSD, and installed Intel Rapid Start Technology in MBR mode, then installed all of the drivers.

I did a thorough diagnostic provided by Dell from the boot-up options.  It says NO ERRORS FOUND.  So the hardware is OK.